# Meaning of "you should have to..."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, modal-verbs

This is an extract from an online book:

> Now that you have Git on your system, you’ll want to do a few things to customize your Git environment. You **should have to** do these things only once on any given computer; they’ll stick around between upgrades.

I know that *should* and *have to* are both modal verbs, and since *have to* is a phrasal modal, their combination is grammatical. But I'm not sure about the meaning of this combination. The combination sounds strange to me. The main usage of *should* is for saying what the correct thing to do is, and *have to* is usually used to express necessity.

There are combinations of modal verbs with clear meaning, for example in "You may not be allowed to enter that room." Here, *may* expresses possibility and *be allowed to* expresses permission. It's clear what is meant by the combination.

Answer (score 3):

The modal "should" expresses expectation. The phrase "have to" expresses obligation: namely the obligation to do something to get a certain result.

So this means "I expect that you will be obliged to run these commands once but you will not be obliged to run them more than once".

Comment: LIke most modals, _should_ has an epistemic meaning (about expectation and knowledge) as well as a deontic meaning (about obligation).